# How can I get different behaviour from class to_s method for string interpolation syntax?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I've written a class that is acting like an array for another class. I have a to_s method which returns in a similar manner to an array when used as follows:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts array
```

This results in the output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

When used with string interpolation `puts "#{array}"` the output is different:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I implement a to_s method in my class to provide both a multiline output for when it is not used in string interpolation and a single line output when it is?

I considered trying to get the caller label with `caller_locations(1,1)[0].label` but this seems far from optimal. Any help or direction to the relevant documentation would be much appreciated, I haven't been able to find anything on the subject yet. Thanks!

Comment: How does your `to_s` look like? Does it return a string or an array?

Comment: My to_s method iterates through a local array and adds a string to an output variable with a newline character and then returns the output variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#to_s` does not (and should not) inspect the context it is called in. The array is printed differently, because `puts` checks if the given argument is an array (or can be converted to an array). From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

You can provide a `to_ary` method:

```
class MyArray
  def to_s
    [1, 2, 3].join('-')
  end

  def to_ary
    [1, 2, 3]
  end
end

a = MyArray.new

puts a        # calls to_ary and then prints each item on a separate line
# 1
# 2
# 3

puts a.to_s   # just prints the result of to_s
# 1-2-3

puts "#{a}"   # same as above
# 1-2-3
```